# Receiving a Sharing Violation Opening a File Code 32

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I have been trying the following piece of code that does not work. What I am trying to do is to start executing my exe (one that I created a simple dialog based application using VC6.0) then from inside this application modify its own contents stored on the hard drive.

So there is a running copy of the exe and from this running copy it will open the disk copy into a buffer. Once loaded into a buffer then begin a search for a string. Once the string is found it will be replaced with another string which may not be the same size as the original.

Right now I am having an issue of not being able to open the file on disk for reading/writing. GetLastError returns the following error "ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.".

So what I did I renamed the file on disk to another name (essential same name except for the extension). Same error again about sharing violation. I am not sure why I am getting this sharing violation error code of 32. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'll ask my second part of the question in another thread.

```
FILE * pFile;

pFile = fopen ("Test.exe","rb");

if (pFile != NULL)
{
     // do something like search for a string
}
else
{
    // fopen failed.
    int value = GetLastError();  // returns 32

    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. First of all I am not trying to write anything that would be consider malicious. I am merely trying to learn how to modify a file that is located on the hard drive but the details of the modification would come from the running instance of the same hard disk file. Nothing more then that. Appreciate the reply.

Comment: Well depending on what you're trying to do, something like [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674\(VS.85\).aspx) might be what you were really after.

Answer (score 2):

Read the Windows part of the [File Locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows) wikipedia entry: you can't modify files that are currently executing.

You can rename and copy them, but you can't change them. So what you are trying to do is simply not possible. (Renaming the file doesn't unlock it at all, it's still the same file after the rename, so still not modifiable.)

You could copy your executable, modify that copy, then run that though.

Comment: That explains the confusion. I have spent all a lot of time just trying to get this part working. At least I know better. Will try out your suggestion. Thanks very much for the reply. Victor